# AVAudioPlayer lot loading audio, given existing path

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to load audio to be setup to different buttons inside the viewDidLoad function. However, my app crashes with this error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    annotateKeys()
    print(constructedArrayOfNotes)


    for key in constructedArrayOfNotes {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: key, ofType: "mp3")
        do {
            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
            player.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayers.append(player)
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }

    }
```

The annotate function constructs the array of `constructedArrayOfNotes`.

The name of the audio file is "PIANO_C3.mp3".

This is the annotateKeys function

```
func annotateKeys() {
    for index in 0...11 {
        constructedArrayOfNotes[index] = "PIANO_" + arrayOfNotes[index] + String(leftSideOfPiano)
    }
    for index in 12...23 {
        constructedArrayOfNotes[index] = "PIANO_" + arrayOfNotes[index] + String(rightSideOfPiano)
    }
}
```

This is what the audio files look like:

[image]

I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong but I'm guessing the path is either not correct or Xcode can't locate the audio file.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is more code:

```
var audioPlayers = [AVAudioPlayer]()

var player = AVAudioPlayer()




// An array with notes C through B is sequenced twice in order to
// traverse the left and right keyboard.
let arrayOfNotes = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"]

var constructedArrayOfNotes = ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `path` will be nil at some point, which means your keys are not set correctly. Replace your function with this

```
 for key in constructedArrayOfNotes {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: key, ofType: "mp3") {
        do {
            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            player.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayers.append(player)
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
      }
    }
```

and see what key is not playing.

Comment: I tried this but it resulted in an empty audioPlayers array.

Comment: what is your `arrayOfNotes` and `leftSideOfPiano` / `rightSideOfPiano`

Comment: It's the current piano octave on both sides

Comment: Paste more code and post a screenshot of those files to see their names

Comment: it's clearly that the path is not correct this is why you get an empty `audioPlayers` array. Did you try to play each sound before the append?

Comment: Okay I posted more pictures. And yes I played each sound.

Comment: Where did you copy those files? Are they in the main bundle?